# Excel-created Outlook appointment only notifies me

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

I am trying to set up an Outlook calendar at work, from Excel data sheets.

I run a query to get data, then treat it, and fill Outlook calendar events.
The problem is, when I enter my required attendees, via my olAppointmentItem, it only notifies me and fills my calendar, not my colleagues' calendars.
I think this might come from the fact that I create it from my own Outlook account.

Here is the mapping of my Excel sheet:
[image]

Here is the code I use:

````vb
Sub RegisterAppointmentList()
    ' adds a list of appointments to the Calendar in Outlook
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olAppItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim row As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("to_be_added").Activate 'worksheet with the list of my appointments to be added

    Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If olApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Outlook is not available!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    row = 2 ' first row with appointment data in the active worksheet
    Dim mysub, myStart, myEnd
    While Len(Cells(row, 2).text) <> 0
        mysub = "Test"
        myStart = DateValue("09/20/2019") + TimeValue("8:00") 'date and time
        myEnd = DateValue("09/20/2019") + TimeValue("9:00") 'date and time
        Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) 
            ' set default appointment values
            .Location = "Office" 'Location of my event
            .Body = "Test appointment" 'title
            .ReminderSet = True
            .BusyStatus = olBusy 'doesn't need to set people busy
            ```
            .RequiredAttendees = "me@company.com" 'this works just fine
            .RequiredAttendees = "colleague@company.com" 'this doesn't work
            ```
            'On Error Resume Next
            .Start = myStart
            .End = myEnd
            .AllDayEvent = False
            .Subject = mysub
            '.Location = Cells(row, 9).Value
            '.Body = Cells(row, 8).Value
            '.ReminderSet = True
            '.BusyStatus = olBusy
            .Categories = "In" 'My own categories (two possibilities, In or Out)
            On Error GoTo 0
            .Save 
        End With
        row = row + 1
    Wend
    Set olAppItem = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
````

I think this is just a parameter that doesn't catch or something, because it works fine on my own calendar, I get reminders as well as events.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  At the very least include test data to be used in the variables.

Comment: The 1st use of `On Error Resume Next` to activate your worksheet is good. The 2nd use to create the Outlook object is good. The 3rd use when setting appointment properties is questionable at best and may well be hiding errors that would explain the issue. Additionally you do `.ReminderSet = True` then `.BusyStatus = olFree`, then set attendees, then you do `.ReminderSet = True` then `.BusyStatus = olBusy` after the 3rd OREN. Just a SWAG, but that may be where the issue is.

Comment: @niton I edited the code to make it test data. Problem is still the same. Sorry about that.
FreeMan thank you for the clarification, indeed it was a bit messy. Didn't solve the problem either, infortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created an appointment with a superfluous `.RequiredAttendees` property.

You did not attempt to `.Send`.

```vb
Sub RegisterAppointmentList_SendMeetingInvitation_Minimal()

    ' Most Excel-related code is removed

    ' Create a meeting from an appointment
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olAppItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem

    Dim myStart As Date
    Dim myEnd As Date

    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If olApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Outlook is not available!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    myStart = DateValue("09/21/2019") + TimeValue("8:00") 'date and time
    myEnd = DateValue("09/21/2019") + TimeValue("9:00") 'date and time

    Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    With olAppItem

        ' set default appointment values
        .Location = "Office" 'Location of my event
        .Body = "Test appointment"
        .ReminderSet = True
        .BusyStatus = olBusy

        .RequiredAttendees = "me@company.com"
        .RequiredAttendees = "colleague@company.com"

        .Start = myStart
        .End = myEnd
        .AllDayEvent = False
        .Subject = "Test"

        ' Change appointment to meeting
        .MeetingStatus = olMeeting

        .Display ' change to .Send when tested

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @niton! It was the .MeetingStatus that had to be set to olMeeting istead of appointment. And the missing .Send also. It works perfectly now!